# vb.net select random folder name

Tags: vb.net, random, directory

Dose anybody know how I can select an existing random directory name (C:\ drive) using vb.net and store its location in a variable.

I had to googel this one but seem to only be able to find example in relation to files, not folders

Comment: You can use my tested answer, if you still did not find any solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, hope this will suits your requirement,

```
'----------------- Global Variables
Dim xCnter = 0
Dim xRndNo = 0
Dim xSubdirectory As String

Private Sub Basement()
     Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
     xRndNo = xGenerator.Next(1, 100)
     AssignRndDirectory("C:\")
     msgbox(subdirectory)
End Sub

Private Sub AssignRndDirectory(xPath as string)
     For Each subdirectory In Directory.GetDirectories(xPath)
        if xCnter = xRndNo then Exit sub
        xCnter += 1
        call AssignRndDirectory(subdirectory)
     Next 
End Sub
```

[Note:  This code is not tested with IDE, Tell me if anything cause errors.]

---

**EDIT:** `TESTED WITH IDE`

```
 Dim xCnter = 0
   Dim xRndNo = 0
   Dim xSubdirectory As String

   Private Sub Basement()

        Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        xRndNo = xGenerator.Next(1, 100)
        AssignRndDirectory("C:\")
        MsgBox(xSubdirectory)

        xCnter = 0

    End Sub

    Private Sub AssignRndDirectory(ByVal xPath As String)

        Try

            For Each Subdirectory In Directory.GetDirectories(xPath)

                If xCnter = xRndNo Then Exit Sub
                xSubdirectory = Subdirectory
                xCnter += 1
                Call AssignRndDirectory(Subdirectory)

            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Just make a list of directories, and select a random item from it.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim path As String = "C:\"
Dim dir = New DirectoryInfo(path)
Dim subDirs = dir.GetDirectories()
Dim randomDir = subdirs(rnd.[Next](subDirs.Length))
```

Or, if you prefer Linq, the last line can be:

```
Dim randomDirectory = subdirs.Skip(rnd.[Next](subdirs.Length)).First()
```

Comment: I assume that OP wants a random file in the directory structure not only in the top directory. Therefore you have to use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` which will give errors if you have no access(for example on [junction points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Try it out on C.

Comment: I read it is `how I can select an existing random directory name [from the] C:\ [directory]`. Perhaps the question author can clarify?

Comment: I want to randomly select a random folder (allready existing) on the C:\ directory

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT Please can you clarify if you want to select this folder from (a) Just the root folder, or (b) The root folder and any subfolders.

Comment: the root folder and any subdirectorys